# The 'import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver' cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, selenium

I am trying to automate an android application,

I have taken following code,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;

public class LaunchElGiftoAndroid {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception

{
    AndroidDriver ad=new AndroidDriver();
    System.out.println("Started");
    ad.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    System.out.println("Application Title"+ ad.getTitle());
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    ad.findElement(By.name("Email")).sendKeys("testing");
    ad.findElement(By.name("Passwd")).sendKeys("type password");
    ad.findElement(By.name("signIn")).click();
    System.out.println("Opened");
    ad.close();

}

}
```

I have installed the Web driver apk properly.

i was getting problem with the following import statement.

import org.openqa.selenium.android.AndroidDriver;

Answer (score 1):

I believe you using the old AndroidDriver.

You should be using Selendroid in that case.

http://selendroid.io/mobileWeb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you check this [webpage](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver). Selenium recommends you to switch to Selendroid as it has more features and options. You can even do automation inside an app!